# QTP fails to recognize Java-applet Jtree object when used with Regular Expression

Tags: applet, qtp, ui-automation

I am using QTP for automating an application. QTP recognizes Java applet- JTree as a html tag. In the html tag we have a number which is dynamic.
Hence we used Regular Expression so that QTP  recognizes the object even if the number changes. But QTP is failing to do so. We have tested the regular expression in the evaluator and it works highlights the correct number as expected. 
The expression in Obj Repository matches with the one in the Expert view.

Reg expressions do not work with html tags/applets is it??

Is there any other way to deal with dynamic elements in html tags??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using descriptive programming it may help you. If you could provide more details of the issue then i could send you code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try UFT that is the next generation of QTP.
If you have a QTP-Licence you can update to UFT and I guess it will work well.
On the other hand how long will QTP will be supported